# Backing up to Azure

Tags: backup, azure

When trying to backup to Azure cloud it fails with the below(drive has 6TB of data) error.
OS: Windows 2012 R2 Standard.

1. I read a few articles about adding a "." with the language section of windows, but this was already present.

Event ID: 12289
Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error DeviceIoControl(\?\Volume{a6337fc7-676b-4208-9ff4-6a85aca89ac7} - 00000000000001A4,0x0053c008,0000007E842B30B0,0,0000007E842B40C0,4096,[0]).  hr = 0x80070057, The parameter is incorrect.
.

Operation:
   Processing EndPrepareSnapshots

Context:
   Execution Context: System Provider

Thank you.

Comment: Details would be nice. Are you using MABS or MARS?

Comment: Or maybe DPM? Which of the Azure backup variations are you testing?